# How to give option to user for input a value in an exe file ?? I have converted py to exe but i want system number to be dynamic in exe installer

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, exe

#### Python Code to generate QR Code in GUI

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import qrcode


def img_taker():
    cs = Tk()
    cs.title('qr_code')


    img = PhotoImage(file='imgdt2.png')
    Label(
        cs,
        image=img
    ).pack()

    cs.mainloop()

def i_saver():
    # Importing library
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    date_time = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    # print("date and time:",date_time)
    # Data to encode
    data = (f"System_no = 1 \n Date and Time:{date_time}")

    # Creating an instance of QRCode class
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version = 1,
                    box_size = 10,
                    border = 5)

    # Adding data to the instance 'qr'
    qr.add_data(data)

    qr.make(fit = True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color = 'black',
                        back_color = 'white')

    img.save('imgdt2.png')

i_saver()
img_taker()
```

Above code is generating qrcode in GUI window that is correct but
I want to convert py to exe that I have already done but ,**I want the system name to be dynamic as an option during the setting up of an application(exe file configuration)**

Here I want a dynamic system number configuration as system number is different for the different device:

[image: here I want a dynamic system number configuration as system number is different for the different device]

Comment: An installer, like the one you show, is itself a program, but not the same one as the one it installs.  It might write a file read by the main program later to make such decisions, but you don't have an installer at all yet.

Comment: so what to do now i have converted py to exe using Inno Setup compiler